# Uncaught ReferenceError: getPrice is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I am trying to run a script. The script needs to show me data from the database. In my script I am using `1 dropdown` and `1 textbox`. When I change the selected value (product) in my dropdown it needs to show the price of the selected value. The price needs to be shown in the textbox.

The script is not working. I tried to figure out what the problem is. I used developer console tool of my browser. The developer console tool gives me the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getPrice is not defined | onchange @ (index):1

Can someone help me with this problem?

The pages that I am using for this script are the following pages:

**index.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forms";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' onChange='getPrice(this.value)' style='width: 100%;'>";
     echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<option value='" . $row["id"]. "'>" . $row["name"]. "</option>";
     }                   
echo "</select>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
<html>
<body>
<!-- Your text input -->
<input id="product_name" type="text">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function getPrice() {

        // getting the selected id in combo
        var selectedItem = jQuery('.product1 option:selected').val();

        // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'get.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: 'id=' + selectedItem,
        success: function(response){
            // and put the price in text field
            jQuery('#product_name').val(response);  
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        },
    }); 
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**get.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) ;
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error) ;
    } 
else 
    {
    $product1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ;

    $query = 'SELECT price FROM forms WHERE id=" . $product1 . " ' ;

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) ;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) 
    {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
        echo "<input type='text' value='";
            echo json_encode($result['price']);
        echo "'>";
    }
    else
        {
        echo "<input type='text' value='";
        echo json_encode('no results') ;
        echo "'>";
        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First close `<script>` tag :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your scripts tags should be before `</html>` and inside `<body>` tag :

```
<html>
    <body>    
    <!-- Your text input -->
    <input id="product_name" type="text">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function getPrice() {

        // getting the selected id in combo
        var selectedItem = jQuery('.product1 option:selected').val();

        // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'get.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: 'id=' + selectedItem,
          success: function(response){
            // and put the price in text field
            jQuery('#product_name').val(response);  
          },
          error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
          },
        }); 
      }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP condition could be simple and you don't need any json encoding, e.g:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) 
{
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
    echo $result['price'];
}else{
    echo 'no results';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Aren't you missing a closing script tag there?  I actually think *that* is the problem, not the location of the script.

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @cale_b, Yes script tag should be closed, but also the code should be in the right place.

Comment: I updated my script (see first post). The `Uncaught ReferenceError` is solved now its getting text from `get.php`. But I get wrong text. The textbox is filled with the text: "<input type='text' value='"no results"'>"